# Download CSV fom Clarifai

Tags: csv, export, metadata, clarifai

Was hoping that there was a simple, turnkey way to download the metadata that Clarifai generates as a .`CSV` file. Ideally I would then take that information, format it, and then upload into our DAM system to round out the metadata for images.

Have looked through their documentation and while interesting, isn't pointing me in an actionable direction. I'm not a coder nor have the time to experiment too much, so wondering if there's something out there.

Comment: Is this still an outstanding problem that would be helpful if you could do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

So there isn't a way currently to do this in bulk, but you can do it image by image if you'd want.  When you look at the image, on the bottom right side you should see the option of either JSON or TABLE for the metadata.

[image]

(The image I posted has an image without metadata but you get the idea).

If that works for what you're looking for you would probably have to scrape the site for the data you want :(.

It might be worth contacting the customer support to request this feature though.